# Angular2: onResize method firing multiple times

Tags: angular

I have requirement to call method whenever window is resize. I am using following code-

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {

}
```

But problem is that, whenever I'm resizing the browser onResize method is firing multiple times.

Comment: How do you resize the browser? If you resize by dragging it will fire multiple times because it get resized on each pixel move and not when you stop with dragging (if this is what you expect). Instead of dragging you can try to maximize and restore down the window, this should fire the event once.

Comment: @hakany I'm resizing using Firefox Responsive Design Mode

Comment: You probably get consecutive events because the resize is gradual (i.e. a few pixels at a time). Will a solution to handle it only once it is done be okay?

Comment: @Meir yes I am looking for single event to be handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The resize might triggers multiple events, to narrow it down to a single event at a time, send all events to a sequence and do a debounce (or throttle with debounce) to handle only what at a time:

```
resizeEvent$: Subject<MouseEvent> = new Subject<MouseEvent>();

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event){
  this.resizeEvent$.next(event);
}
```

Then in your constructor, or ngOnInit:

```
this.resizeEvent$.debounceTime(100).subscribe(this.actualResizeHandler);
```

This will ensure that only 100 mSec after the last resize event fired you'll process resize, hence ignoring the multiple events. Note that this might lead to starvation cause as long as you have events, the debounce will block. Another approach will be to to chunk it, in this example to every 500 mSecs:

```
this.resizeEvent$.throttleTime(500).debounceTime(490).subscribe(this.actualResizeHandler);
```

The throttle provides that only the first event in each 500 mSecs will trigger, dropping the following ones, the debounce provides you actually do the work on the end of the period, it will work because the throttle ensures there are no other event during that period and the debounce eventually triggers.

Two things to **note**:

1. The event you get might be 'old', meaning, don't rely on the data it holds, query the size information directly from your component.
2. The debounce period is a bit shorter to prevent race condition and timing issues.